# Copy Key Cell (Col A, Row n) to Audit Log when value (Col C, row n) changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that tracks a number of variables applicable to specific documents.  The document names are unique and reside in Column A.  Any change to the document Status (Column C) writes data (Sheet, Cell Address, User, Time & Date) to an Audit Log.  Since Column A acts like a key, I need to write that to the Log so users don't have to track down the Cell Address but I can't seem to make it work.  Column A (the key) is a named range (ALERT_NAME).

Here's a copy of the code thus far that is working.  How can I add the respective ALERT_NAME (from Col. A) for each entry to the Log?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "Insert Code for Named Ref =ALERT_NAME"
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & "-" & Target.Address(0, 0)
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.UserName
Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:E").AutoFit
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is to replace this end of line:
Value = "Insert Code for Named Ref =ALERT_NAME"

With this:
Value = ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(Target.Row, 1)